# How FormAction works in rasa core?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Below story is mentioned in rasa core docs -

### happy path

- request_restaurant

  - restaurant_form
  - form{"name": "restaurant_form"}
  - form{"name": null}

My interpretation is if a reponse is passed to rasa core with intent "request_restaurant" then it will call "restaurant_form" action which is basically a form-action and form policy jumps in to handle coming requests.

But I am unable to understand what is use of below two lines.

- form{"name": "restaurant_form"}
- form{"name": null}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one
`form{"name": "restaurant_form"}` is activating the form and the second one `form{"name": null}` is deactivating the form again.
This makes more sense when looking at the unhappy path:

```
## chitchat
* request_restaurant
    - restaurant_form
    - form{"name": "restaurant_form"}
* chitchat
    - utter_chitchat
    - restaurant_form
    - form{"name": null}
```

Here the form stays active while performing actions outside the form and is only deactivated after filling all requested slots from the form.

Comment: so what "restaurant_form" does?

Comment: `- form{"name": "restaurant_form"}` is necessary for core during training to activate the form. Actions don't run during training, so all events returned by `Action.run(...)` such as slots, forms, etc have to be put into the stories

Comment: `- restaurant_form` is just a label